# understanding about stackoverflow underlying software infrastructure

Tags: hadoop, redis, stack-overflow

I wonder what all databases/combination of databases stack overflow uses underneath, managing extensive user profile information over various verticals.

As i case of social networking sites like twitter and facebook the Big Data managemnet is done over hadoop. Is stack overflow also handles such higher volumes of data?

How about indexing the information , is redis part of stackoverflow solutions?

It will be really interesting to understand solution deployed at world most popular technical forum .

Answer (score 1):

This article provides a glimpse at what stackoverflow's architecture looks like circa March 2011: http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/3/3/stack-overflow-architecture-update-now-at-95-million-page-vi.html

At a high level, its a .NET application which uses MS SQL server for a database, Redis for caching, HAProxy for load balancing, and a whole host of tools and hosted on both windows servers and linux servers (ubuntu+centos).

It doesn't look like they had any hadoop usage at the time of that article, but that could have changed. They might also be doing something different/custom for map/reduce type jobs or might not need anything like that at all yet. With delicacy, SQL servers can be scaled pretty far without needing to lean on "big data" toys. This is especially true if you can get most of your data out of your caching layer.